# I want to take run an executable and take input from a text file and then write the output in Windows cmd

Tags: c, windows, cmd, io-redirection

In ubuntu I would do it by following command

```
./a.out < input.txt | cat > ouput.txt
```

how can I do this in Windows cmd?

Comment: file.exe c:\yourinput.txt > c:\output.txt ??

Comment: `a.exe < input.txt > output.txt` (PS: you probably don't need the `cat` in Linux, `./a.out < input.txt > output.txt` should work.

Comment: I don't think Windows has `cat`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it in two lines:

```
a.exe < input.txt >output.txt
type output.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work assuming that a.exe writes to STDOUT:

```
a.exe < C:\path\to\input.txt > C:\path\to\output.txt
```